# How can I handle weblogic stuck threads?

Tags: java, linux, database, unix, weblogic

I am using weblogic servers [ different versions all with the same kind of error ]
stuck thread , is there anyway that I could terminate the threads which are stuck without doing a restart for the managed server that has them , threads dump contain wait on lock , and sometimes on acquire database connnection

Here Adding the StackTrace as requested :

```
  ===== FULL THREAD DUMP ===============
Thu Jul  6 07:08:48 2017
Oracle JRockit(R) R28.2.7-7-155314-1.6.0_45-20130329-0641-linux-x86_64
"Main Thread" id=1 idx=0x4 tid=11192 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/t3/srvr/T3Srvr@0x80893c88[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/t3/srvr/T3Srvr.waitForDeath(T3Srvr.java:981)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/t3/srvr/T3Srvr@0x80893c88[fat lock]
    at weblogic/t3/srvr/T3Srvr.run(T3Srvr.java:490)
    at weblogic/Server.main(Server.java:71)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"(Signal Handler)" id=2 idx=0x8 tid=11193 prio=5 alive, native_blocked, daemon
"(OC Main Thread)" id=3 idx=0xc tid=11194 prio=5 alive, native_waiting, daemon
"(Code Generation Thread 1)" id=4 idx=0x30 tid=11203 prio=5 alive, native_waiting, daemon
"(Code Optimization Thread 1)" id=5 idx=0x34 tid=11204 prio=5 alive, native_waiting, daemon
"(VM Periodic Task)" id=6 idx=0x38 tid=11205 prio=10 alive, native_blocked, daemon
"ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=25 idx=0x70 tid=11220 prio=5 alive, blocked, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Blocked trying to get lock: java/lang/String@0x8080b4e0[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForUnblockSignal()V(Native Method)
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.fatLockBlockOrSpin(Locks.java:1411)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.lockFat(Locks.java:1512)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStageHard(Locks.java:1054)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStage(Locks.java:1005)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnter(Locks.java:2179)[optimized]
    at weblogic/socket/EPollSocketMuxer.processSockets(EPollSocketMuxer.java:153)
    at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
    at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=26 idx=0x74 tid=11221 prio=5 alive, blocked, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Blocked trying to get lock: java/lang/String@0x8080b4e0[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForUnblockSignal()V(Native Method)
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.fatLockBlockOrSpin(Locks.java:1411)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.lockFat(Locks.java:1512)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStageHard(Locks.java:1054)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStage(Locks.java:1005)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnter(Locks.java:2179)[optimized]
    at weblogic/socket/EPollSocketMuxer.processSockets(EPollSocketMuxer.java:153)
    at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
    at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=28 idx=0x7c tid=11223 prio=5 alive, blocked, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Blocked trying to get lock: java/lang/String@0x8080b4e0[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForUnblockSignal()V(Native Method)
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.fatLockBlockOrSpin(Locks.java:1411)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.lockFat(Locks.java:1512)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStageHard(Locks.java:1054)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStage(Locks.java:1005)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnter(Locks.java:2179)[optimized]
    at weblogic/socket/EPollSocketMuxer.processSockets(EPollSocketMuxer.java:153)
    at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
    at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"Thread-17" id=40 idx=0xa0 tid=11300 prio=5 alive, parked, native_blocked
    -- Parking to wait for: java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@0x80875f10
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.park0(J)V(Native Method)
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.park(Locks.java:2230)
    at sun/misc/Unsafe.park(ZJ)V(Native Method)
    at java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156)
    at java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987)
    at java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:399)
    at weblogic/utils/concurrent/JDK15ConcurrentBlockingQueue.take(JDK15ConcurrentBlockingQueue.java:89)
    at weblogic/store/internal/PersistentStoreImpl.getOutstandingWork(PersistentStoreImpl.java:672)
    at weblogic/store/internal/PersistentStoreImpl.run(PersistentStoreImpl.java:721)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"DFW Diagnostic Dump Sampling - JavaClassHistogram" id=42 idx=0xa8 tid=11304 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: [B@0x808761a8[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at oracle/dfw/sampling/DumpSampling.run(DumpSampling.java:547)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: [B@0x808761a8[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"DFW Diagnostic Dump Sampling - JVMThreadDump" id=43 idx=0xac tid=11305 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: [B@0x80876388[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at oracle/dfw/sampling/DumpSampling.run(DumpSampling.java:547)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: [B@0x80876388[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"oracle.dfw.impl.incident - ADR Executor (created: Wed Jul 05 07:14:17 IDT 2017)" id=47 idx=0xbc tid=11310 prio=5 alive, parked, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Parking to wait for: java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@0x80876598
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.park0(J)V(Native Method)
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.park(Locks.java:2230)
    at sun/misc/Unsafe.park(ZJ)V(Native Method)
    at java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156)
    at java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987)
    at java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:399)
    at java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957)
    at java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:917)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"oracle.dfw.impl.incident.ADRHelper - purge incidents" id=49 idx=0xc4 tid=11312 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: java/util/TaskQueue@0x80876680[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/util/TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:509)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: java/util/TaskQueue@0x80876680[fat lock]
    at java/util/TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"oracle.dfw.incident.IncidentCreatorThread" id=50 idx=0xc8 tid=11313 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: java/util/ArrayList@0x80876740[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at oracle/dfw/impl/incident/DiagnosticsDataExtractorImpl$IncidentCreatorThread.run(DiagnosticsDataExtractorImpl.java:2144)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: java/util/ArrayList@0x80876740[fat lock]
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"oracle.dfw.incident.FloodController" id=54 idx=0xd8 tid=11318 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: java/lang/Object@0x80876808[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at oracle/dfw/impl/incident/FloodController.run(FloodController.java:136)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: java/lang/Object@0x80876808[fat lock]
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"Thread-33" id=62 idx=0xf8 tid=11328 prio=5 alive, parked, native_blocked
    -- Parking to wait for: java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@0x808768c0
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.park0(J)V(Native Method)
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.park(Locks.java:2230)
    at sun/misc/Unsafe.park(ZJ)V(Native Method)
    at java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156)
    at java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987)
    at java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:399)
    at weblogic/utils/concurrent/JDK15ConcurrentBlockingQueue.take(JDK15ConcurrentBlockingQueue.java:89)
    at weblogic/store/internal/PersistentStoreImpl.getOutstandingWork(PersistentStoreImpl.java:672)
    at weblogic/store/internal/PersistentStoreImpl.run(PersistentStoreImpl.java:721)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"weblogic.cluster.MessageReceiver" id=63 idx=0xfc tid=11329 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: java/util/ArrayList@0x80874d60[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/cluster/messaging/internal/server/UnicastFragmentSocket.receive(UnicastFragmentSocket.java:105)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: java/util/ArrayList@0x80874d60[fat lock]
    at weblogic/cluster/FragmentSocketWrapper.receive(FragmentSocketWrapper.java:98)
    at weblogic/cluster/MulticastManager.run(MulticastManager.java:466)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=64 idx=0x100 tid=11330 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x80874510[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:162)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x80874510[fat lock]
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:183)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"DynamicListenThread[Default]" id=66 idx=0x104 tid=11339 prio=9 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/net/PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Ljava/net/SocketImpl;)V(Native Method)
    at java/net/PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
    ^-- Holding lock: java/net/SocksSocketImpl@0x82aaceb8[biased lock]
    at java/net/ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
    at java/net/ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:430)
    at weblogic/socket/WeblogicServerSocket.accept(WeblogicServerSocket.java:38)
    at weblogic/server/channels/DynamicListenThread$SocketAccepter.accept(DynamicListenThread.java:535)
    at weblogic/server/channels/DynamicListenThread$SocketAccepter.access$200(DynamicListenThread.java:417)
    at weblogic/server/channels/DynamicListenThread.run(DynamicListenThread.java:173)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=67 idx=0x108 tid=11340 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x808745f8[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:162)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x808745f8[fat lock]
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:183)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=68 idx=0x10c tid=11341 prio=1 alive, blocked, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Blocked trying to get lock: oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CConnection@0x98ba7960[thin lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.sleep(I)V(Native Method)
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.waitForThinRelease(Locks.java:955)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStageHard(Locks.java:1083)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.monitorEnterSecondStage(Locks.java:1005)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/PhysicalConnection.rollback(PhysicalConnection.java:5116)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/OracleConnectionWrapper.rollback(OracleConnectionWrapper.java:147)
    at weblogic/jdbc/wrapper/XAConnection.rollback(XAConnection.java:861)
    at weblogic/jdbc/wrapper/Connection.forcedCleanup(Connection.java:153)
    at weblogic/common/resourcepool/ResourcePoolImpl.timeoutInactiveResources(ResourcePoolImpl.java:1953)
    at weblogic/common/resourcepool/ResourcePoolImpl.access$1500(ResourcePoolImpl.java:41)
    at weblogic/common/resourcepool/ResourcePoolImpl$ResourcePoolMaintanenceTask.timerExpired(ResourcePoolImpl.java:2675)
    at weblogic/timers/internal/TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:273)
    at weblogic/work/SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=69 idx=0x110 tid=11407 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x805517e8[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:162)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x805517e8[fat lock]
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:183)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=70 idx=0x114 tid=11408 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x8054ff60[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:162)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x8054ff60[fat lock]
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:183)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '7' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=71 idx=0x118 tid=11409 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x80545b08[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:162)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x80545b08[fat lock]
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:183)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=72 idx=0x11c tid=11410 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x8051c030[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:162)
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x8051c030[fat lock]
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:183)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"Thread-9057" id=9097 idx=0x5b8 tid=28822 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at jrockit/net/SocketNativeIO.readBytesPinned(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;[BIII)I(Native Method)
    at jrockit/net/SocketNativeIO.socketRead(SocketNativeIO.java:32)
    at java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;[BIII)I(SocketInputStream.java)
    at java/net/SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at oracle/net/nt/MetricsEnabledInputStream.read(TcpNTAdapter.java:730)
    at oracle/net/ns/Packet.receive(Packet.java:302)
    at oracle/net/ns/DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:108)
    at oracle/net/ns/NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:317)[optimized]
    at oracle/net/ns/NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:262)[optimized]
    at oracle/net/ns/NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:187)[optimized]
    at oracle/net/ns/NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:104)
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:126)[inlined]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:82)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1178)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:314)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:205)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:548)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:217)[inlined]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:947)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1283)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1441)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleStatement.doScrollExecuteCommon(OracleStatement.java:6629)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/OraclePreparedStatement.doScrollPstmtExecuteUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:13502)[inlined]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3767)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3823)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CConnection@0x94d824b8[thin lock]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1671)[optimized]
    at weblogic/jdbc/wrapper/PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:135)[optimized]
    at com/test/provide/operations/GlobalOperations.getQueueHistoryResult(GlobalOperations.java:2293)[optimized]
    at com/test/provide/SwitchProvisioning.getResultMessageForGeneralCase(SwitchProvisioning.java:102)[optimized]
    at com/test/provide/SwitchProvisioning.access$1300(SwitchProvisioning.java:73)
    at com/test/provide/SwitchProvisioning$ProcessThreadClassGUI.parseProvisioningXMLGUI(SwitchProvisioning.java:9562)
    at com/test/provide/SwitchProvisioning$ProcessThreadClassGUI.run(SwitchProvisioning.java:8010)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
"Thread-7800" id=7840 idx=0x620 tid=25129 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at jrockit/net/SocketNativeIO.readBytesPinned(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;[BIII)I(Native Method)
    at jrockit/net/SocketNativeIO.socketRead(SocketNativeIO.java:32)
    at java/net/SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;[BIII)I(SocketInputStream.java)
    at java/net/SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at oracle/net/nt/MetricsEnabledInputStream.read(TcpNTAdapter.java:730)
    at oracle/net/ns/Packet.receive(Packet.java:302)
    at oracle/net/ns/DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:108)
    at oracle/net/ns/NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:317)[optimized]
    at oracle/net/ns/NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:262)[optimized]
    at oracle/net/ns/NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:187)[optimized]
    at oracle/net/ns/NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:104)
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:126)[inlined]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:82)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1178)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:314)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:205)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:548)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:217)[inlined]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:947)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1283)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1441)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleStatement.doScrollExecuteCommon(OracleStatement.java:6629)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/OraclePreparedStatement.doScrollPstmtExecuteUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:13502)[inlined]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3767)[optimized]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3823)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CConnection@0x98ba7960[thin lock]
    at oracle/jdbc/driver/OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1671)[optimized]
    at weblogic/jdbc/wrapper/PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:135)[optimized]
    at com/test/provide/operations/GlobalOperations.getQueueHistoryResult(GlobalOperations.java:2293)[optimized]
    at com/test/provide/SwitchProvisioning.getResultMessageForGeneralCase(SwitchProvisioning.java:102)[optimized]
    at com/test/provide/SwitchProvisioning.access$1300(SwitchProvisioning.java:73)
    at com/test/provide/SwitchProvisioning$ExecuteThreadClass.saveProvRequest(SwitchProvisioning.java:2444)
    at com/test/provide/SwitchProvisioning$ExecuteThreadClass.run(SwitchProvisioning.java:759)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
Blocked lock chains
===================
Chain 2:
"ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=26 idx=0x74 tid=11221 waiting for java/lang/String@0x8080b4e0 held by:
"ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=27 idx=0x78 tid=11222 in chain 1
Chain 3:
"ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=28 idx=0x7c tid=11223 waiting for java/lang/String@0x8080b4e0 held by:
"ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=27 idx=0x78 tid=11222 in chain 1
Open lock chains
================
Chain 1:
"ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=25 idx=0x70 tid=11220 waiting for java/lang/String@0x8080b4e0 held by:
"ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=27 idx=0x78 tid=11222 (active)
Chain 4:
"[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=68 idx=0x10c tid=11341 waiting for oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CConnection@0x98ba7960 held by:
"Thread-7800" id=7840 idx=0x620 tid=25129 (active)
===== END OF THREAD DUMP ===============
```

Regards,

Comment: There is no way to stop threads without restarting the servers. You should work on the root cause and correct your code. You can also consider increasing your connection pool if you do not have enough database connections.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin the problem is not with my code , the problem that sometimes get Connection from database become unresponsive at some point , checked the database and the connection between the server and the database and found nothing at that area , some times weblogic just get stuck on its own [ can't seem to put my finger at the cause exactly when this issue happens ]

Comment: Can you share one or tow thread dumps when the issue occurs ?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 threads blocked on a JDBC socket read call. My recommendation would be to configure a read timeout for these connections. The Oracle JDBC thin driver has a property called "oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout" which can be set to a number of milliseconds you're willing to wait. By default there is no timeout and the system level tcp socket read timeout will kick in. You can try 5 seconds by setting the value to "5000".